# How to move files and make directory simultaniously and paste in that new folder using one command in BASH

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

How to move files and make directory simultaniously and paste in that new folder using one command in BASH
I am trying to do this by using this command but its not working:

```
cp *.docx /home/ahmed/my-files/first-semester | mkdir islamiyat
```

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO6yP.png)

Comment: Hi, please do not put an image or your code, put it in the question.  Especially for a one liner!  Look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir -p dirxyz && mv *.docx ./dirxyz
```